# React Native Error when running React-Native run-android

Tags: android, reactjs, typescript, react-native, mobile

I get this strange error in VScode when I try to execute the command React-native run-android in the terminal.

Also ran react-native doctor and all green checkmarks for Node,yarn, android_home, and android sdk 0 errors

Not sure how to fix these issues as I have tried all suggestions in previous threads. Anyone have this issue that could assist? This is a windows machine.

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UC66g.png)

Answer (score 0):

1.first Gradle needed to connect to the internet.

2.cd android

./gradlew clean

./gradlew wrapper

./gradlew -v   // to download the new version

3.project app-level build.gradle file:

update version this

com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics

and this

com.google.gms:google-services